# Chrome Extension - Are content script matches limited to permissions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension, and was looking at my manifest.json file and realized something:

I have permissions for sites like this:

```
"permissions": [
    "*://*.google.com/*",
    "*://*.twitter.com/*",
]
```

If I use `<all_urls>` for my **content script**, will it be limited to *only* Google and Twitter domains? Or will it also inject the script into other websites despite not having permission?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration),

> If your content script's code should always be injected, register it in the extension manifest using the content_scripts field. If you want to inject the code only sometimes, use the permissions field instead.

I believe `all_urls` will override the permissions. After testing this on one of my extensions which uses `all_urls`, it did in fact work on non-google/twitter domains. I then clicked on the permissions link on my extension in `chrome://extensions` and it told me that the extension can "read and change all your data on the websites you visit"

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for the quick and complete answer. c:

Comment: @Awesomolocity is there a way to not show "read and change all your data on the websites you visit", but still use content scripts on all pages?

Comment: @Goehybrid I don't think so, but you can always explain why you need the permissions / what the permissions mean in the "overview" section on the webstore.